# Laravel 5.2: Class "Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider" not found during composer installation

Tags: php, laravel-5, composer-php

So I've been trying to install the LaravelCollective/Html package via `composer update` (already added `"laravelcollective/html": "5.2.*"` to the project composer.json file), but I keep getting this...

```
  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
  Class 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider' not found


Script php artisan optimize handling the post-update-cmd event returned with error code 1
```

It seems I need to update app.php, but only **after** the install I can't get out of.

Thanks in advance.

(Oh and I'm using Windows, if that's of any importance. And yes, I did look for answers, but most were either relative to people having trouble after install or wrongly assuming they were)

Answer (score 0):

So, I ended up finding the answer myself. I really dislike when I ask for help and end up not needing any, but this answer might be useful for others thinking the same way as I did.

Some answers I looked for said something about using `composer dump-autoload` after installation. I didn't try this step because I was fixated on the installation failing, and assumed it only worked if the install itself did. But then I decided to go with it, then retried `composer update` and nothing happened (maybe a sign there was nothing broken to fix). Then I edited the *config/app.php* file as explained on the [docs](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html) and, surprisingly, it started working. I still might need to test it a little, but for now it seems nothing's broken.